# Need help understanding how a specific getter affects my program

Tags: java, swing, methods, action, getter

I'm very new to coding(2 months) and i attempted to make Tic-Tac-Toe in java. I'm in a little over my head but i managed to create it using swing. My main problem is in the `button1` class. I was going to use the `getText()` method but ended up not needing it or so i thought. I tried deleting it but as it turns out my tictactoe buttons don't switch letters without it. The compiler told me it overrides `AbstractButton`'s `getText()` method but i don't see why that should matter since i never actually used it i thought. I'm thinking it's maybe a scope issue handled by it being overwritten somehow but i'm not sure. I was trying to use the `text` variable to update the button with `setText()` and that doesn't seem to work like i thought it should. I also don't understand why the 3 by 3 gridlayout seems to work properly most of the time but sometimes the number of buttons added is wrong.

So in summation the program works(mostly) but i'm not fully understanding how the `button1` class is working.

TicTacToe.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setSize(600, 600);
    window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

    ArrayList<button1> buttonArrayList = new ArrayList<>(9);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        button1 newbutton = new button1();
        buttonArrayList.add(newbutton);
        window.add(buttonArrayList.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

button1.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class button1 extends JButton {
int value = 0;
String text = "";

public button1() {

    class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonAction() {}
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Switcher) {
            System.out.println(text + " " + value);
            value++;//value is a relic from earlier attempts that i just felt like keeping.
            if (text.equals("O")) {
                text = "X";
            } else if (text.equals("X")) {
                text = "";
            } else if (text.equals("")) {
                text = "O";
            }
        }
    }
    this.setAction(new ButtonAction());
    this.setText(text);
    this.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,120));
}

public String getText()// <----culprit
{
    return text;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JButton class has a methods defined for it, including `setText()` (which will set the displayed text on the button) and `getText()` (which will return the current text that is displayed on the button).

You created a class button1 (note: classes should start with Capital Letters).

You added an Action to the button1 class, which means that when the action is activated, something happens. Note that in that `actionPerformed` method, you should call `setText(text)` to update the displayed value.

You have also defined a `getText()` method that overrides the `getText()` method defined in JButton. This approach is fine if it is a conscious design decision. As it is, I think you should remove the `getText()` method from the button1 class, and allow the standard JButton class to handle the update. Right now, you are attempting to keep an instance variable `text` with the value, but it is possible for that instance variable to not be in alignment with the actual displayed value of the button (consider another class calling `.setText()` on the button).

**EDIT**: It is true that `this` referring to the JButton in the ButtonAction is not available. However, the Action itself contains the button that was pressed.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();

        // if desired, String cur = btn.getText() may be called to find the
        //  current setting; get and process if needed
        btn.setText(WHAT_EVER_TEXT);
    }
```

Unless it is a specific requirement to process the current text, however (allowing selecting an O to an X to a blank), I would implement something to keep track of the current turn. This code is something I was experimenting with, and has good and bad points to it (as it is illustrative):

```
static class TurnController
{
    // whose turn it is; start with X
    private Player whoseTurn = Player.X;

    // the instance variable
    private static final TurnController instance = new TurnController();


    private TurnController()
    {
    }

    public static Player currentTurn()
    {
        return instance.whoseTurn;
    }

    public static Player nextTurn()
    {
        switch (instance.whoseTurn) {
        case X:
            instance.whoseTurn = Player.O;
            break;

        case O:
            instance.whoseTurn = Player.X;
            break;
        }

        return instance.whoseTurn;
    }

    public static String getMarkerAndAdvance()
    {
        String marker = currentTurn().toString();

        nextTurn();

        return marker;
    }

    enum Player
    {
        X,
        O,
        ;
    }
}
```

Using this TurnController, the `actionPerformed` becomes:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();

        btn.setText(TurnController.getMarkerAndAdvance());
    }
```

and the Button1 class may have the `String text` instance variable removed.

Comment: If i'm understanding your suggestion correctly you're saying to set the text on the button from the `actionperformed` method. If that is so then that is what i wanted to do from the start but I didn't know how to implement it properly. I still don't know actually, i know i cant use `this.` in there. Would you mind showing me how to do that. Thanks btw

Comment: @ApatheticWrath, made an edit to the answer to try to help illustrate how to get the selected button from the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: It's going to take me a bit to fully wrap my head around that new class but i think i'll get it. The one thing that throws me off is exactly what this line means and does `JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();`. It references the button it's in and sets things through a local instance of the button?

Comment: @ApatheticWrath, the `ActionEvent` object contains a reference to the object that that generated the event. Since the `ButtonAction` was added to the Button1 class, the selected widget is a JButton. The variable `btn` is scoped to the `actionPerfomed` method, but references the button that was selected. It is not a local instance, as it is referencing the instance of the JButton that was pressed. That button was instantiated in the `main` method.

Comment: I get your words but i don't get the why. it seems like `btn` is a local variable of `actionPerformed` that is just a copy of the instantiated button in main. Since it looks like it's just being assigned the same value. So why is it that `btn` can effect the button in the arraylist. Sorry if i seem dense this is all very new I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: `btn` is a local variable. However, the fact that it is a _local variable_ does not change the fact it can refer to an Object instantiated elsewhere. It is most definitely _not a copy_. The variable `btn` is assigned to the **same instance**  of the `button1` class that was instantiated in `main`. Because it is assigned to the same instance, it can affect the button.  If you are writing this in an IDE, use a debugger to look at the instance references. If you are still confused, I would suggest posting as a new question, as perhaps others can explain in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried is Try to make a Custom `Button` Class  and its `EventHandler` just by extending `AbstractAction` namee `button1` as we See in Your Question.

You have Override the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent Switcher)` which actually belongs to Class `AbstractAction` by your own definition **(What should Performed on Action Event of Every Button)**.

```
 class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonAction() {}
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Switcher) { // Your Definition For actionPerformed..
            System.out.println(text + " " + value);
            value++;//value is a relic from earlier attempts that i just felt like keeping.
            if (text.equals("O")) {
                text = "X";
            } else if (text.equals("X")) {
                text = "";
            } else if (text.equals("")) {
                text = "O";
            }
        }
    }
    this.setAction(new ButtonAction()); // add ActionListener to each Button.
    this.setText(text); // Setting Text to each Button
    this.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,120)); //add Font to each Button.
}
```

Now In this Code.

ArrayList buttonArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    button1 newbutton = new button1(); // Creating 9  new buttons.
    buttonArrayList.add(newbutton); // add each button into the ArrayList.
    window.add(buttonArrayList.get(i)); // each Button to the the AWT Window.
}
```

Above Code will generate `9` Button and add it to Your `AWT Window`. each `button` have `actionPerformed()` method which contains the `overrided` Definition.

Now Each button will performed action as per the definition you give to `actionPerformed()` Method.

Thank You.